# Magento 1.9: Add custom block to header

Tags: magento

I have this in my local.xml.

```
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="wc-customheadblock" template="wc-customheadblock.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

Inside wc-customheadblock.phtml i have:

```
<div style="height:100px; background-color:green">

<h1>This is the wc custom head block</h1>

</div>
```

But this block is not appearing in the header. I've tried the same for the sidebars (by changing the xml reference name) and it works just fine. Why does this not work for the header?

This site claims its possible to make add blocks to the header using local.xml!
http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout

Comment: Add inside the header.phtml $this->getChildHtml('wc-customheadblock'). Maybe left & right have $this->getChildHtml().

Comment: show your full code in local.xml file

Comment: How `local.xml` defined in your `config.xml`

Comment: provide full code inside `local.xml` file and show us the file path to these two files

Comment: I maintain my point. Just tried it and it worked.

Comment: @SamuelComan : if that is the case, post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your header.phtml file (app/design/frontend/package/theme/page/html/header.phtml) and place one of the following lines:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('wc-customheadblock'); ?>
```

Most likely header doesn't render child blocks by default because it would cause some template crashes. On the sidebars, extra childs can be easily appended at the end.

Comment: you forgot to mention that, core/template block should contain `as` attribute in it ?

Comment: I used exactly the xml posted by aDvo and it worked. Don't know if that's required or not.

Comment: This worked, thanks @SamuelComan ... However i'm curious about the "as" attribute. Can't seem to find much documentation, maybe "as" is too generic a word. What is it for?

Comment: It's for adding an alias. Like in SQL. If your block name is to long, you can use the name placed in as.